# SQL Server / SSRS - Use stored procedure to update data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure which once I've put my parameters in a SSRS report I would like to update the data in the columns reason_for_exceptioning, notes, and exceptioned depending what I put into the parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExceptionOutages]  

  @start_date datetime
  ,@hostname2 nvarchar(max)
  ,@error_flag bit

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE  PostExceptionMatchingTable      
SET [reason_for_exceptioning] = @reason_for_exceptioning
,[notes] = @notes
,[exceptioned] = @exceptioned

SELECT [client]
  ,[hostname]
  ,[hostname2]
  ,[hostname_2]
  ,[os]
  ,[measure]
  ,[end_seconds]
  ,[start_seconds]
  ,[error_flag]
  ,[end_datetime]
  ,[start_datetime]
  ,[end_date]
  ,[start_date]
  ,[datetime_difference]
  ,[outage_seconds]
  ,[percentage]
  ,[inc_number]
  ,[inc_brief_description]
  ,[inc_status]
  ,[inc_description]
  ,[inc_priority]
  ,[inc_sla_breach_exception]
  ,[inc_sla_breach_reason]
  ,[inc_status2]
  ,[inc_report_date]
  ,[inc_resolve_date_target]
  ,[inc_affected_user_company]
  ,[crq_number]
  ,[crq_brief_description]
  ,[crq_description]
  ,[crq_change_timing]
  ,[crq_start_date]
  ,[crq_end_date]
  ,[crq_outage_start_date]
  ,[crq_outage_end_date]
  ,[crq_priority]
  ,[crq_request_status]
  ,[Expr1]
  ,[wlg_log_date]
  ,[wlg_description]
  ,[wlg_detailed_description]
  ,[submit_date]
  ,[hour_difference]
  ,[day_difference]
  ,[reason_for_exceptioning]
  ,[notes]
  ,[exceptioned]
FROM [availability_outages].[dbo].[PostExceptionMatchingTable]
where [start_date] = @start_date
and [hostname2] = @hostname2
and [error_flag] = @error_flag

END
```

I'm not entirely sure where to put the update in the stored procedure

Comment: Just write a update statement before select statement.

Comment: I have updated the code above but I'm getting scalar variable errors

Comment: where are reason_for_exceptioning, notes, and exceptioned from?

Comment: They are three parameters which are columns in the SELECT statement from the PostExceptionMatchingTable. What I input into the parameters I want it to update in the Table

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `UPDATE` before the select statement. The `UPDATE` should work in any part of the Stored Procedure as long as inside the `BEGIN..END` block.